# Convergence in $L^p$ space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space.

Let $1<p < \infty$. Suppose $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence in $L^{p}(\mu)$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n g d\mu$ exists for every $g \in L^{q}(\mu)$.

Find $f \in L^p(\mu)$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n g d\mu = \int fg d\mu$.

I thought that the last part requires the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. But the assumptions don't meet the assumptions to apply the theorem here.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we allow the limit of $\int f_n gd\mu$ to depend on $g$, then the function $f$ could be any element of $L^p\pr{\mu}$ (take $f_n=f$).

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n gd\mu$ is not allowed to depend on $g$, then (replacing $g$ by $-g$), one gets that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n gd\mu=0$ and only $f=0$ can work, since $\int fgd\mu=0$ for each $g\in L^q(\mu)$ implies that $g=0$.